# Error: Syntax error (missing operators) in query expression?

Tags: vb.net

When ever I click on the UPDATE button it showing me the error as "Syntax error (missing operators) in query expression" but the save and refresh functions are working fine. I don't know what is the syntax error in the update button.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub FillDataGridView(ByVal Query As String)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, cn)
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    With DataGridView1
        .DataSource = dt
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Name"
        .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Age"
        .Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
    Try
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$] where ID='" & TxtId.Text & "'")
        TxtFamilyname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "insert into [edit$]values('" & TxtId.Text & "','" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "', '" & TxtAge.Text & "')"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("successfully Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where id ='" & TxtId.Text & "' where Age= '" & TxtAge.Text & "'"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("Successfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a massive sql injection security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND` with `WHERE` clause between two or more conditions

```sql
 where id ='" & TxtId.Text & "' AND Age= '" & TxtAge.Text & "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't have single quotes around your `id` and `age` fields (assuming these are numeric data types) Also - you have two `where` clauses which is not allowed.

So it should look more like this:

```
.CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where id =" & TxtId.Text & " AND Age= " & TxtAge.Text
```

But having said that you shouldn't write sql queries like this anyway. Search for [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/), then search for [parameterised queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) - you don't need to worry about single quotes when using parameterised queries

Answer (score 0):

You cant have two where clauses...

Use "AND"/"OR" to extend your query.

[SQL AND & OR Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `where` clauses in the `update`. Use `and` between the conditions:

```
.CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where id ='" & TxtId.Text & "' and Age= '" & TxtAge.Text & "'"
```

That said, your code is wide open for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should rather use parameterised queries than to concatenate the values into the queries. Example:

```
With cm
  .Connection = cn
  .CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = @name where id = @id and Age = @age"
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TxtFamilyname.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TxtId.Text)
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", TxtAge.Text)
  .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

Comment: Can some one explain me that how to delete the data of a row in my excel sheet DB from datagridview through a Delete button "BtnDelete"

Comment: @shaikizaz: You should start by looking if there are some already existing answers that would be useful, otherwise you can ask a new question to reach the persons who knows about it. You posted this as a comment to an answer in a question that isn't all related to your new question, so you only reached me, and anyone who just happens to read this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.. I'll post it as a question now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two WHERE statements in your Update CommanText, try the following;

```
.CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where id ='" & TxtId.Text & "' and Age= '" & TxtAge.Text & "'"
```